# Default c-shell, change to bash but allow for scp

Tags: scp, csh

Hi so I am trying to modify my .cshrc file to make bash my default. It is on a school account so I cannot change the main settings but can change the profile. The problem is that when I use the command:

```
bash
```

in my .cshrc it works when I am logging in just fine. But anytime I try to scp files it does not work because it launches the .cshrc and scp gets confused when it changes to the bash terminal.

Does anyone know how to get around this? Possibly launch bash in quiet mode...

Comment: You've tried `chsh` and it doesn't work? Or are you simply assuming your can't change your shell?

Comment: Are you sure `ypchsh` didn't work?  If it did, you'll have to logout and login again for it to take effect.  If not, contact your system administrator(s); they'll be able to change your login shell for you.  Until then, I suggest just invoking `bash -l` manually (perhaps via an alias) as I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't do anything that invokes an interactive application or produces visible output in your `.cshrc`.  The problem is that `.cshrc` is sourced for non-interactive shells.  And since your default shell is csh, you're going to have csh invoked non-interactively in a lot of cases -- as you've seen with `scp`.

Instead, I'd just invoke `bash` -- or, better, `bash -l` -- manually from the csh prompt.  You can set up an alias like, say, `alias b bash -l`.

If you're going to invoke a new shell automatically on login (which is still not a good idea), put it in your `.login`, not your `.cshrc`.

This is assuming `chsh` doesn't work, but it should -- try it.

Comment: Placing the `bash` command in the .login is working. What potential problems do you see if I place `bash` in the .login instead of using the command at the prompt? @KevinThompson

Comment: Good question.  I'm not actually sure that it will cause any problems, but it does remove the option of running your default shell if you want to.  (And again, you want `bash -l` rather than just `bash`; it should be a login shell.)